# MongoDB: Unique and sparse compound indexes with sparse values

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to store the following link:

```
URL = {
  hostname: 'i.imgur.com',
  webid: 'qkELz.jpg'
}
```

I want a unique and sparse compound index on these two fields because:

1. A combination of `hostname` and `webid` should be unique.
2. `webid` will always be queried with `hostname`.
3. `webid` need not be globally unique.
4. A `URL` need not have a webid.

However, when I do this, I get the following error:

```
MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error index: db.urls.$hostname_1_webid_1  dup key: { : "imgur.com", : null }
```

I guess in the case of compound indexes, nulls are counted, whereas in regular indexes, they are not.

Any way out of this problem? For now I'm just going to index `hostname` and `webid` separately.

Comment: For [unique indexes](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Indexes#Indexes-unique%3Atrue) (compound or otherwise) you cannot have identical keys. You should be able to insert a single record with (hostname, null) but the second with identical hostname will be a duplicate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Keep in mind that mongodb can only use one index per query (it won't join indexes together to make a query on two fields that have separate indexes faster).

That said, if you want to try to check for uniqueness, you could do a query from the app before inserting (which only partially solves the problem, because there's a gap between when you query and when you insert).

You might want to vote on this JIRA issue for filtered indexes, which will probably help your use case:
https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-785

Comment: oh. so how does it decide which index to work on? i already check for uniqueness before inserting.

Comment: It has a couple different query plans that it choses from based on the collection and the query: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Optimization