# How to find mongo documents with a same field

Tags: mongodb

I have a mongo collection, and I need to find documents in this collection, in which fields name and address are equal.

I have searched a lot, I could only find [MongoDb query condition on comparing 2 fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4442453/mongodb-query-condition-on-comparing-2-fields) and [MongoDB: Unique and sparse compound indexes with sparse values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11386674/mongodb-unique-and-sparse-compound-indexes-with-sparse-values), but in these questions they are looking for documents in which field a = field b, but I need to find document1.a == document2.a

Comment: How would you understand what `document2` is? Is it a case of finding all duplicates?

Comment: So you want to find duplicates?

Answer (score 120):

You can find duplicates using the [Aggregation Framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation/) and [`$group`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/group/).

Example data set up:

```
// Batch insert some test data
db.mycollection.insert([
    {a:1, b:2, c:3},
    {a:1, b:2, c:4},
    {a:0, b:2, c:3},
    {a:3, b:2, c:4}
])
```

Aggregation query:

```
db.mycollection.aggregate(
    { $group: { 
        // Group by fields to match on (a,b)
        _id: { a: "$a", b: "$b" },

        // Count number of matching docs for the group
        count: { $sum:  1 },

        // Save the _id for matching docs
        docs: { $push: "$_id" }
    }},

    // Limit results to duplicates (more than 1 match) 
    { $match: {
        count: { $gt : 1 }
    }}
)
```

Example output:

```
{
    "result" : [
        {
            "_id" : {
                "a" : 1,
                "b" : 2
            },
            "count" : 2,
            "docs" : [
                ObjectId("5162b2e7d650a687b2154232"),
                ObjectId("5162b2e7d650a687b2154233")
            ]
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: +1 very nice thanks a lot (for Mongovue users remove comments //)

Comment: Hi @Stennie can we restore database after delete it? Or either its collections?

Comment: @Ashh Hopefully you have a backup you can restore from (or perhaps a delayed secondary?). There's no "undo" for deleting data.