# How to find duplicates when queried by a certain field in Mongo Db collection using Spring data

Tags: mongodb, spring-data

Is there a way to find duplicate records ( all occurrences of the duplicates) in a mongo Db collection when queried by a particular field. I am using Spring-data. There is a similar question in SO: [Mongo find duplicates for entries for two or more fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35624531/mongo-find-duplicates-for-entries-for-two-or-more-fields)

But I would like the duplicated values(documents), not the counts. Is this possible?

Comment: What is critieria for duplicate documents ? all fields same or some key

Comment: @Veeram : one key

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$push` operator with the the group stage in the aggregation pipeline, to add the duplicate values into an array.