# How to get all duplicates documents in mongodb collection?

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection which have multiple duplicate records,
I want to fetch all duplicates in the entire collection.
Records are like this:

`a:1,b:2,c:3,
a:1,b:2,c:3,
a:4,b:3,c:3,
a:1,b:3,c:3,
a:1,b:7,c:3,
a:1,b:2,c:3`

expected output:`{a:1,b:2,c:3},{a:1,b:2,c:3},{a:1,b:2,c:3}`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mongo find duplicates for entries for two or more fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35624531/mongo-find-duplicates-for-entries-for-two-or-more-fields)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First add a group stage which will group according to the parameters you want to group (in this case a,b and c)

Then find the values which have more than 1 occurrence of the parameters you grouped

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
      "$group": {
        "_id": {
          "a": "$a",
          "b": "$b",
          "c": "$c"
        },
        "count": {
          $sum: 1
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "$match": {
        "count": {
          "$gt": 1
        }
      }
    }
  ])
```